# IIS7 - Change physical path of all sites in server config

Tags: windows-server-2008, migration, iis-7, iis-7.5

I've been trying to migrate an IIS7 webserver (rather large one), and so far am appalled by the state of msdeploy and using it for what I need to do. Enough on that, here's my current problem:

The server I'm migrating from has all the sites on a `D:\` drive. It isn't possible for us to have a `D:\` drive in the new environment, so I need to change all the site paths to `C:\`. I obviously do not want to do this for each site manually, so I thought to edit the paths in `applicationHost.config`. However, IIS doesn't seem to care one bit. All the paths are C:\, yet IIS still tries to reference `D:\`. When I look at site settings, it still says `D:\`. Where in the world is this value coming from?

It's on a 64-bit server, and I checked the OTHER `applicationHost.config` in `\syswow64\`, and that has magically changed to `C:\` as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: "Fixed" it by copying applicationhost.config to a 2003 box, editing it there and copying back. Apparently 2008 "pretends" to save your file (i.e. it shows my changes when I open it in notepad) but read them from, either some cached version, or from another file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fixed" it by copying applicationhost.config to a 2003 box, editing it there and copying back. Apparently 2008 "pretends" to save your file (i.e. it shows my changes when I open it in notepad) but read them from, either some cached version, or from another file elsewher

Answer (score 0):

There should be a relatively simple using the correct syntax in MSDeploy.

Better than trying to explain all of the ins-and-outs of the process here, I'd recommend reading [this thread at iis.net](http://forums.iis.net/t/1157598.aspx)

Make sure you go through the whole thread before starting a migration.

Comment: Hey. I'd read that already. Sadly the person who posted there had a very different setup. He was running IIS 6 with sub-apps. We're running IIS 7 with individual apps. I will however play with the migrate verb a bit now. Any idea where the actual physicalPath values are stored for the sites though?

Comment: Sorry, the only physicalPath I know of off the top of my head is the one that's located in applicationHost.config -- There must be another "global" location to store this, but I don't recall running into it.